# Deploying and Interacting with smart Contract through infura from web3.py

Tags: solidity, infura, testrpc-to-ropsten

I'm trying to deploy smartcontract on ropsten testnet through infura node in web3.py. here is my code

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://ropsten.infura.io/<*Privatekey>"))


# Instantiate and deploy contract
contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

# Get transaction hash from deployed contract
tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': w3.eth.accounts[0], 'gas': 410000})

# Get tx receipt to get contract address
tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']
```

when I run this code, I always ended up getting timeout error. what could be the possible reason for it. every answer is appreciable because atleast you have spent time on this question.

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout is 10 seconds as far as I remember, so you can try changing it to 60 seconds.

Change this:

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("..."))
```

To this:

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("...",request_kwargs={"timeout":60}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code internally calls `sendTransaction` function that is not supported by Infura.  Also you use `w3.eth.accounts[0]` which is also not supported.  You need to use local private keys, when working with Infura.  See [Web3.py documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#working-with-local-private-keys) for more details.